# MongoDB (NoSQL) - Can a document reference/link to itself?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am very new to the NoSQL side of DBs but I have been using RDBMs for years, primarily MySQL.

Right now, in MySQL, I have a database that holds about 10,000 food items (about to add another 15,000) that contain items, which links to attributes and nutrients. This seemed to be like a good use for NoSQL as far as my research has taken me, but one part makes me think it might not be.

From what I can tell there are absolutely no joins in NoSQL (very happy for the simplicity), but right now we have several food items that are somewhat the same, and they are going to all reference one, for instance:

```
Tomatoes, Raw
Tomatoes, Canned
Tomatoes, Cooked
```

What I am going to do is make all of them reference the main object, "Tomatoes, Raw" or just "Tomatoes", but they all contain their own set of attributes and nutrients, and are rightfully their own "food item".

In RDBM this is simple, simply adding a `primary_item_id` field to the `item` table and referencing the main item.

Is this possible in MongoDB, or should I stick with MySQL?

-Kerry

Comment: Everything in MongoDB is schema-free, so you can do what you want. Your analysis should center around the queries that you are interested in doing.

Comment: I need to be able to look up the related items by the primary item. Would I have to create my own IDs and their own fields? Is there an auto increment?

Comment: Start here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/ All documents must have a unique `_id`. If you don't provide one, it's autocreated (it's an `ObjectId` in MongoDB). No, there isn't an autoincrement field, but there are ways to emulate the functionality in some cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same thing in MongoDB i.e. Tomatoes can be main item with say _id=1 and these items will have parent id as 1. The collection can be noted as:

`{ { 1, "Tomatoes", null }, { 2, "Tomatoes, Raw", 1 }, { 3, "Tomatoes, Canned", 1 }, { 4, "Tomatoes, Cooked", 1 } }`

Note that you can keep parentid in main item as null for query purposes (as I did above) or you can just remove that column if you do not need it (and it works as MongoDB is schema free.)